# Ubuntu 18.04 UEFI issue

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, kubuntu, uefi

Background:
I recently installed KUbuntu 20.04 on a Dell UEFI laptop, and, being somewhat new to issues with UEFI, I was pleased that the installer complained when I, not being used to the need for a small UEFI partition on a new drive, attempted to set up the drive withOUT creating a UEFI partition. After doing so, the install went perfectly.

Now to my question;

I needed to install Gnome Ubuntu 18.04 on another UEFI laptop, and expected to be able to create said UEFI partition. I created a 500Mb partition and then went looking for the partition use choice. There didn't appear to be one. Hmm.. Google showed me a tutorial with screenshots of setting up the UEFI partition on 18.04 and the screenshot that clearly showed an "EFI" partition choice was nowhere to be found in my case.

These two laptops are my first experience with UEFI, since all of my laptops previously have had legacy bios. I used the manual partitioning menu choice on both systems, and as I said, the 20.04 one warned me about not having a UEFI partition and when I went to create it there WAS a menu selection for such a partition. I cannot find same in 18.04.. What AM I missing here???

Comment: Just for fun I tried installing 20.04 Gnome Ubuntu on the second UEFI laptop and IT also had no choice for uefi partition and gleefully let me install to 35Gb / and the remaining space on 500Gb SSD to /home, without warning me about a uefi partition or even giving me the option of CREATING one, and of course it wouldn't boot. As I said earlier, KUbuntu 20.04 DID warn me and gave me a menu choice to create a uefi partition. Anybody?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to dual boot on your second UEFI laptop? The UEFI partition [does not really matter](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) if you are not planning to dual/multiple boot. See bullet #3 below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OP here. Found the problem. I didn't realize that the flash drive with the Ubuntu ISO had to be partitioned/formatted GPT/UEFI. Once I fired up
my Windows VM and installed Rufus and used that to make the install flashdrive, I was able to install Ubuntu on the second laptop.

Thanks!